Suitability of QR factorization for solving a ill-conditioned linear system.
I am trying to solve a linear system $Ax = b$ where
$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
2&  9&  2&  1&  4&  1&  0&  0&  0 \\
9& 65&  9&  1&  4&  1&  0&  0&  0 \\
2&  9&  2&  1&  4&  1&  0&  0&  0 \\
1&  1&  1&  2&  5&  2&  1&  8&  1 \\
4&  4&  4&  5& 17&  5&  1&  8&  1 \\
1&  1&  1&  2&  5&  2&  1&  8&  1 \\
0&  0&  0&  1&  1&  1&  1&  8&  1 \\
0&  0&  0&  8&  8&  8&  8& 64&  8 \\
0&  0&  0&  1&  1&  1&  1&  8&  1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and A is ill-conditioned and singular. I have decided to solve the system in a least-squared sense by QR factorization of $A$ into the product of the orthogonal matrix $Q$ and the upper triangular matrix $R$, using the Householder method. However during the process of QR factorization I noticed that some diagonal elements of $R$, shown below
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1.03440804e+01&  -6.17744617e+01&  -1.03440804e+01&  -3.57692501e+00&  -1.25675744e+01&  -3.57692501e+00&  -5.80041893e-01&  -4.64033515e+00&  -5.80041893e-01\\
0.00000000e+00&  -2.42675892e+01&  -1.56036495e-16&  4.69608314e+00&  1.50964785e+01&  4.69608314e+00&  1.22928468e+00&  9.83427745e+00&  1.22928468e+00\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -2.05323646e-15&  -2.64610272e-01&  -2.64610272e-01&  -2.64610272e-01&  -2.64610272e-01&  -2.11688218e+00&  -2.64610272e-01\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -8.19038412e+00&  -8.19038412e+00&  -8.19038412e+00&  -8.19038412e+00&  -6.55230729e+01&  -8.19038412e+00\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -2.04418448e-15&  -4.82955896e-15&  -4.80506304e-15&  -3.84405043e-14&  -4.80506304e-15\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  2.48208983e-15&  2.53068420e-15&  2.02454736e-14&  2.53068420e-15\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -1.09555726e-17&  -8.76445805e-17&  -1.09555726e-17\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  4.96874996e-32&  6.21093745e-33\\
0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are so small, e.g. $−2.05323646−15$, that they seem to have been zero-ed out during the process.
Therefore I was wondering what this says about the suitability of the QR factorization for solving such a linear systems. Would GMRES for example be a better method?

Update
As @copperhat pointed out the original matrix has repeated columns, so here is another matrix
$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 53 &   83 &  101 &  119 &  133 &  161 &    0 &    0 &    0 \\
 83&  130&  158&  187&  209&  253&    0&    0&    0 \\
101&  158&  194&  221&  247&  299&    0&    0&    0 \\
119&  187&  221& 1130& 1222& 1464& 1189& 1247& 1363 \\
133&  209&  247& 1222& 1322& 1584& 1271& 1333& 1457 \\
161&  253&  299& 1464& 1584& 1898& 1517& 1591& 1739 \\
  0&    0&    0& 1189& 1271& 1517& 1681& 1763& 1927 \\
  0&    0&    0& 1247& 1333& 1591& 1763& 1849& 2021 \\
  0&    0&    0& 1363& 1457& 1739& 1927& 2021& 2209
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with non-repeating columns AFAICS, but whose facrorization produces an $R$ matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2.78693380e+02&  -4.37505907e+02&  -5.21540914e+02&  -2.06983388e+03&  -2.24480036e+03&  -2.69183646e+03&  -1.99061420e+03&  -2.08771733e+03&  -2.28192360e+03\\
 0.00000000e+00&  7.62349509e-01&  -6.86114558e+00&  8.40100714e+02&  8.99300515e+02&  1.07385052e+03&  1.15108324e+03&  1.20723365e+03&  1.31953445e+03\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -7.22714360e-13&  -4.79826007e+01&  -5.12917456e+01&  -6.12191802e+01&  -6.78374700e+01&  -7.11466148e+01&  -7.77649046e+01\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  2.20128739e+03&  2.35310031e+03&  2.80853908e+03&  3.11216493e+03&  3.26397785e+03&  3.56760370e+03\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  3.48673102e-13&  6.79970467e-13&  1.88237140e-13&  3.01758615e-13&  6.42902231e-14\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  2.35448168e-13&  -6.69362848e-15&  -1.54702891e-14&  -4.32877439e-14\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -1.64085428e-13&  1.81948529e-14&  -3.15564299e-14\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -2.14238677e-13&  7.10530473e-15\\
 0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  0.00000000e+00&  -1.66984181e-13
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with elements in the upper triangular part of the matrix zero-ed out.

GMRES uses QR, so I am not sure how that would improve things. Without more knowledge, you won't do much better than QR.

@Moo I used numpy, but you can see that the result of the website you linked is not upper triangular i.e. many elements in the upper triangular part of $R$ are zero-ed out.

What are you expecting exactly, there 3 rows that are repeated, so there is really no surprise with fp arithmetic?

@copper.hat Thanks for the observation. I have provided an alternative matrix the factorization of which produces a similar problem.

You could take the SVD decomposition, keep the non-too small singular values (and associated singular vectors), then "reconstruct" your matrix from that.

Possibly relevant reading, not a solution https://nhigham.com/2021/05/19/what-is-a-rank-revealing-factorization/
